# binding observable collection data list to Single hubtile and display data One after other in windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, observablecollection, silverlight-toolkit

Hi Every one I have some data in observable collection data list  Now i need Bind this Data to Single Hub tile and Display the data One by One with Some Time Gap

Im going to this [Articles](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api) But Hub tile display only first item form Observable data List

Comment: Couldn't get you? How do you want the request to be fulfilled? explain more briefly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313307/tile-animation-in-windows-phone-inside-the-app ............Need to display Like that tile Breaking news ....

Answer (score 0):

Data binding is such an extensive topic, that you should definitely start with an [intro article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/80555/Databinding-in-Silverlight-applications). Also, there is a great [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) that shows what the proper binding path syntax is, which is of great help.